# SCPI command SYSTem:ERRor?

Tags: scpi

I need to send some SCPI to a power supply IT6000C.

Part of the code is to check if the instrument is in over voltage protection (OVP) or current protection (OCP).

I don’t manage to find a SCPI Command to control it. I have found only SYSTem:ERRor? (at page 249 of the user’s manual), but it return always 0 (no error) even if the instruments in error.

Surfing in internet, it should be quite easy and the command is standard. I wonder if I have to do something more.

Comment: My experience is that instruments from companies other than Keysight/Tek/NI often take a fairly fast & loose approach to implementing SCPI. It might just be that your instrument is not standard compliant. A link to its manual might help us give you a more useful answer.

Comment: @ThePhoton Exactly- Even Keysight and Tek can vary greatly between revisions and generations.  Second and third tier instruments are all over the place.

Answer (score -1):

the user's manual is possible to get from the following link.

https://eur.itechate.com/en/info_128.aspx?itemid=416&lcid=84

Thanks in advance
Fausto

Comment: Can you please explain the system command in this answer if the link goes down this answer will be worthless

Comment: Horrible website (https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2DMO.png). I don't mind the bad grammar so much, since they're from CN. But clicking on 'No, thanks' does nothing. A product has to be REALLY amazing, that I'm willing to create an account just to read the user's manual.